# Building Qt libraries for VS2012 runtime - update

Tags: visual-studio-2012, qt5

I need to build and link the latest (5.0.1) Qt libraries against the VS2012 runtime libraries.
I’m using the non-commercial Qt.
I’ve downloaded the qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.1 package and now I’m stuck on some problems:
Apparently there is no proper cookbook on how to configure and build for vs2012 compatibility.

My configure command line is:

```
configure –I C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include –I C:\OpenSSL-Win32 –I C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include\openssl   -opensource -openssl-linked -debug-and-release -platform win32-msvc2012 –no-icu -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

The error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ssleay32.lib'
```

Tried to add the libraries to the configure command, by adding to the previous command line:

```
-l C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\ssleay32.lib  -l C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\libeay32.lib
```

.. and got a funny link error:

```
 LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ssleay32.lib.lib'
```

Tried again:

```
-l C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\ssleay32  -l C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\libeay32
```

got the first link error again.
Also tried using the -L switch with no help.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: *update*: overcame the above error and bumped into another:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Using a vanilla copy of the package, used the winner command line - removing the explicit -l and adding -L(SSL lib directory).

Thanks for watching!